# Checkbox не изменяет состояние

Tags: knockoutjs

Код [тут](http://jsfiddle.net/parampampam/gby3m5f4/1/).
При нажатии на чекбоксы видно, что значение active меняется, но условие

```
attr: { checked: f.active() == '1' }
```

не выполняется. Почему так происходит?

В коде убрал много лишнего, чтобы не мешало.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, ошибка на стороне knockout. Но и ваш код - тоже странный.

Привязка булевого значения к чекбоксу обычно делается так:

```
checked: f.active
```

Заметьте: тут нет вызова функции, так же как и привязки `attr`. И тем более не надо обрабатывать событие `click` там, где knockout это умеет делать сам.

Если вам нужно непременно число 1/0 вместо true/false - можно использовать декоратор:

```
checked: $root.wrapIntToBool(f.active)

//...

ViewModel.wrapIntToBool = function(f) {
  return ko.pureComputed({
    read: function () { return f() },
    write: function (v) { f( v ? 1 : 0) },
  })
}
```